# update user info in postgres database through html app (php)

Tags: php, html, postgresql

its a pretty basic "change username" component im tyring to get working. if someone can tell me specifically what code to implement that would be great. (im learning php).

and im getting the typical function() supposed to have parameter resource blah blah...

my intended result is just to have the posted username (new username) update to the old username in the database and then read it back to the user on screen.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !==true) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$newusername=$_POST['newusername'];
$oldpassword=$_POST['oldpassword'];

$query="UPDATE public.users 
        SET (username,password) = 
        ('$newusername','$oldpassword')
        WHERE username= '$_POST('username')' and password = '$_POST('password')'";

    $result=pg_query($dbconn,$query);
    $row_count= pg_num_rows($result);
            pg_free_result($result);
            if($result){
                $_SESSION["username"] = $newusername; 
                pg_close($dbconn);

            }
   }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'" data-toggle="modal" id="update" style="width:auto;">Profile</button>
<div id="id03" class="modal">
  <form class="modal-content animate" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="currentusername"><b>Current Username: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></b></label>
      <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Username" name=" newusername" required>

      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input id="input" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="oldpassword" required>
        
      <button id="logininmodal" name="submit" type="submit">Confirm Changes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button id="cancel" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First bug to fix: Change all $_GET to  $_POST please (your form is using POST as method to submit).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. _POST variables are controlled by the user and an attacker can thus choose them to do all sorts of monkey business on your database.

It is okay to use a simple query like yours in the case that the data has been sanitized, such as if you use a function like `preg_replace` to filter them for only alphanumeric characters, or for integers, typecasting to (int) is sufficient, but in the absence of a restriction like this, you need to use a prepared statement. That is, instead of having one line where you call `pg_query`, first call `pg_prepare`, which returns a resource that you can then pass to `pg_execute` in a second statement. In the text of the prepared statement, use wildcards (`?`) in place of variables, and then pass the variables in the execute. Both of these are well-documented on the PHP websites and you can find ample examples of them.

As for how to debug your code, rather than give you a specific answer I will try to tell you how to debug this in general:

If a query isn't working, first test the query. Usually I achieve this by (on a test box, not a production server) adding the lines:

```
echo $query;
die();
```

and running the script. Then I have a separate terminal in which I connect directly to postrgesql using the `psql` command line tool, using the same username as in the script, and then I paste the query in, and I see if postgres gives me an error. If it's a problem in the query itself, I fix it here.

If the query works as generated by the PHP script, then I know the problem lies in the subsequent calls. Look at the errors generated to figure out what is going on.

Looking at your code, I think I found the answer which is that, unless there is some earlier code being executed, you haven't actually connected to your database. Your query statement references the `$dbconn` variable, but I don't see any initialization of the connection. First you need to connect to the database and return a valid connection variable. Test the connection to see if it is working and debug that first.

I suspect that if you fix this, the rest of your code will work. But I would warn you, *you absolutely do not want that code to go live without first securing it* or this could allow your database to be compromised.